# Error in implementing a basic string to integer converter

Tags: c

I am writing a basic C program which will take the input of a string, then convert it to an integer. I am aware of the standard atoi() function, this is purely an exercise I set myself. The code for the program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char input[20];
    int counter, temp, magnitude = 0, value = 0;
    scanf("%s", input); //takes user input for string to convert
    for (counter = strlen(input); counter >= 0; counter--) { //from last to first char of input
        temp = input[counter] - '0'; //converts from ASCII to actual value and stores in int
        value += temp * magnitude * 10; //temp to correct magnitude and adds to total
        magnitude++; //increments magnitude counter
    }
    printf("%d\n", value); //prints result
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to iterate backwards from the end of the string, then convert each character to it's actual value from ASCII, then convert it to the correct magnitude, before finally adding it to the final value. It is giving me values which are generally close although wrong.

For example 256 gives 220 and 90 gives 180.

Comment: regarding this line:  scanf("%s", input); 1) code should check the returned value from scanf to assure the conversion/input was successful. 2) there needs to be a following line that checks that input actually contains some data.  3) scanf does not null terminate a string input, so the line: char input[20]; should be: char input[20] = {'\0'}; so what ever is input is properly terminated.  However, scanf, as written, does not limit the length of the input string, suggest: using fgets(data, sizeof(data), stdin);  Then the code needs to replace the trailing .\n' with '\0' before continuing

Comment: the code needs to iterate from left to right to find the last char in the initial sequence of the input that is in the range '0'...'9' as the user could have entered (for instance) 12b709.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.  Firstly, you're also trying to convert the terminating NUL byte, which doesn't make sense.  Start iterating at `strlen(input) - 1`.

Second, for the magnitude you want to exponentiate, not multiply, i.e. 10, 100, 1000 rather than 10, 20, 30.  For this, you can use `pow()`, for example:

```
for (counter = strlen(input) - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) { //from last to first char of input
    temp = input[counter] - '0'; //converts from ASCII to actual value and stores in int
    value += temp * pow(10, magnitude); //temp to correct magnitude and adds to total
    magnitude++; //increments magnitude counter
}
```

Comment: this is wrong,  strlen() does not include the trailing null byte,

Comment: @user3629249: It does not include it in the count, however strings are indexed from zero... so s[length] is the NUL byte.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` gives the total length of the string. So you have to use

```
counter = strlen(input)-1
```

In your for loop. This is because arrays in C start from `0` and end at `strlen -1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = strlen(input)
```

should be

```
counter = strlen(input) - 1
```

so you're using the last valid character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here. 
1) You should ignore the string null-terminator, so going from `strlen(input)-1` will do 
2) Your calculation is wrong. You should not multiply by magnitude, but raise 10 to it's power. Or simpler, it itself the required 10's power:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char input[20];
    int counter, temp, magnitude = 1, value = 0;
    scanf("%s", input); //takes user input for string to convert
    for (counter = strlen(input)-1; counter >= 0; counter--) { //from last to first char of input
        temp = input[counter] - '0'; //converts from ASCII to actual value and stores in int
        value += temp * magnitude ; //temp to correct magnitude and adds to total
        magnitude*=10; //increments magnitude counter
    }
    printf("%d\n", value); //prints result
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While your approach should work (after the issues noted in other answers have been fixed, anyway), it's probably simpler to take this approach:

```
value = 0;
for (char *p = input; *p; ++p)
  value = value * 10 + (*p - '0');
```

That eliminates a couple unnecessary extra variables, and is probably a bit more efficient. It might not hurt to change the `for` loop termination condition to `*p && isdigit(*p)` - that would terminate the conversion on the first non-digit character seen, which might be a desirable approach for dealing with invalid input...

Answer (score 0):

```
here is a complete answer,
that includes good programming paradigm practices
and defensive coding against user input problems
and results in the right answer

#include <stdio.h>  // fgets(), exit(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h> // EXIT_FAILURE, perror()
#include <string.h> // strlen()
#include <ctype.h>  // isdigit()

int main () // <-- do not use void
{
    char input[20] = {'\0'};
    int counter; // index into input array
    int value = 0; // initialize the converted int from string

    if( NULL != fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) ) 
    { // fgets failed
        perror( "fgets failed for string input");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets successful

    // note no need to replace trailing '\n' in following code block
    for( counter=0; isdigit(input[counter]); counter++)
    {
        value = value*10 + (input[counter]-'0');
    } // end for


    printf("the converted value from %s is: %d\n", input, value); //prints result
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```